# Pattern iterator

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator

I have a task, which consists of pattern implementation (Iterator) and addition of the method iterator() in previously created classes Hotel and Tours. Unfortunately, I'm still new to Java, so I don't know how to use methods from IIterator for arraylist inter. Info - interface

```
public class IIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private Object elements;
    int index = 0;


    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index< Array.getLength(elements);
    }
    public T next() {
        return (T) Array.get(elements, index++);
    }
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
    }
}
public class Hotel implements Info, Serializable, Cloneable, Comparable{
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new IIterator();
    }
}
public class Tours implements Info, Serializable, Cloneable, Comparable{
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new IIterator();
    }
}

ArrayList<Info> inter = new ArrayList();
        inter.add(new Hotel("Lara", 100, 5));
        inter.add(new Hotel("Katya", 10, 1));
        inter.add(new Tours("Lara", 1000, length));
        inter.add(new Tours("HelsinkiPanorama", 1010, length));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Iterator is a property of a list not of an object. You need to elaborate more. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: for (IIterator<Info> itr = (IIterator<Info>) inter.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) 
System.out.println(itr.next()); 
It shows an error

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to use Iterator in this case

Comment: Only collections are iterable. Is Hotel a collection? If so, then what is it a collection of? Same question applies to Tours.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

you can do this:

```
    for (Info info : inter) {
        System.out.println(info.getString());
    }
```

or

```
    Iterator<Info> it = inter.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next().getString());
    }
```

---

**Previous answer**

I'm not sure about your question, but if you want a simple example of iterator you can see this:

```
public class Hotel {

    private String name;

    public Hotel(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Tours implements Iterable<Hotel>{

    private List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHotel(Hotel  hotel){
        hotels.add(hotel);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Hotel> iterator() {
        return hotels.iterator();
    }        
}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tours tours = new Tours();
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-0"));
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-1"));
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-2"));
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-3"));

    for (Hotel hotel : tours) {
        System.out.println(hotel.getName());
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
hotel-0
hotel-1
hotel-2
hotel-3
```

If you want to see an example under the hood

```
public class Tours implements Iterable<Hotel>{

    private int numHotels = 0;
    private Hotel[] hotels = null;

    public void addHotel(Hotel  hotel){
        if (hotels == null){
            hotels = new Hotel[5];
        } else if ( numHotels + 1 >= hotels.length){
            hotels = Arrays.copyOf(hotels, numHotels + 5);
        }
        hotels[numHotels++] = hotel;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Hotel> iterator() {
        return new HotelIterator();
    }

    private class HotelIterator implements Iterator<Hotel> {
        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < numHotels;
        }

        @Override
        public Hotel next() {
            return hotels[index++];
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tours tours = new Tours();
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-0"));
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-1"));
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-2"));
    tours.addHotel(new Hotel("hotel-3"));

    for (Hotel hotel : tours) {
        System.out.println(hotel.getName());
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
hotel-0
hotel-1
hotel-2
hotel-3
```

Comment: I need to have both Hotel and Tours in my ArrayList
ArrayList<Info> inter = new ArrayList();
        inter.add(new Hotel("Lara", 100, 5));
        inter.add(new Hotel("Katya", 10, 1));
        inter.add(new Tours("Lara", 1000, length));
        inter.add(new Tours("HelsinkiPanorama", 1010, length));
Where Info-Interface

Comment: @JuliaK You must to post your Info interface.

Comment: public interface Info extends Cloneable, Iterable, Comparable {
    int getInt();
    void setInt(int reserved);
    int getM(int r, int num);
    void setM(int r, int num);
    String getString();
    void setString(String name);
    int fun();
    NameDto find(String nmName, int nmrm, int length);
    Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
    void output(OutputStream out) throws IOException;
    void write(Writer out) throws IOException;
    int[] getM();



}